# Multiply output of subquery (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to multiply the result of a subquery with a field from the 'main' query. See the following example:

Table: subscriptions

- id
- title
- price

Table: users

- subscription_id

```sql
SELECT 
    subscriptions.id,
    subscriptions.title,
    (select count(*) from users where users.subscription_id = subscriptions.id) AS qty
    SUM(qty * subscriptions.price) AS total
FROM subscriptions
```

This gives the error `Unknown column 'qty' in 'field list'`. So it seems like the result from the subquery isn't available in the SELECT field. After searching StackOverflow I found some of the same questions and it seems I need to move the subquery from the select to a JOIN. This seems simple enough but I'm having trouble to modify my own query to work like this. Anyone who can push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the subquery in the `SELECT` list, join with it.

```
SELECT s.id, s.title, u.qty, s.price * u.qty AS total
FROM subscriptions AS s
JOIN (
    SELECT subscription_id, COUNT(*) AS qty
    FROM users
    GROUP BY subscription_id
) AS u ON s.id = u.subscription_id
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I noticed a JOIN is also faster (in my case) than using a subquery in the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Almost right.

```
SELECT 
    s.id,
    s.title,
    SUM(s.price * (select count(*) from users u where u.subscription_id = s.id)) AS total
FROM subscriptions s
GROUP BY s.id, s.title
```

Comment: Assuming `s.id` is the primary key, there's no need for `SUM` and `GROUP BY`, since there's just one row in each group.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reslove your query, check it

https://dbfiddle.uk/xrMrT7Y4

I don't know why someone has deleted my answer. Here I found issue in your query is you didn't group the aggregate function & If you are comparing ID then both tables should be considered. @Vinze

Comment: Yeah I saw your answer, no idea why it was removed.. But thanks for clearing things up!